# Python recursive problem not checking every availiable possibility

Tags: python

[Question picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK3x8.png)

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. The code is suppose to try multiple ways to get to the value of 42 and after exhausting all existing tries, the output would be false. I do not think my code is doing that and only checking it once. In the question picture above, there is an example that used 250 as an example with multiple ways to solve it. My output with my code is False where it should be true. Any idea how to fix this or approach this?

```
def bears(n: int) -> bool:
    if n == 42:
        return True

    elif n < 42:
        return False

    else:

        if (n % 2 == 0):
            return bears(n // 2)
        if (n % 3 == 0) or (n % 4 == 0):
            return bears(n - (int(str(n[-2]))*int(str(n[-1]))))
        if (n % 5 == 0):
            return bears(n - 42)
    return False

print(bears(250))
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text - just provide a brief description or the relevant section in your question. Linking to the image for the full details is fine. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: How do you know your code is only checking once? Do you have any print statements to check what it is doing? What is the number is not divisible by either 2, 3 or 5 but still higher than 42? According to the code, we return False immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking only one path because you stop checking alternatives after trying once. You immediately return the value of the first call, for example in:

```
return bears(n // 2)
```

If `bears(n // 2)` doesn't lead to the answer, you don't check the other possibilities, but just return `False`.

A fixed solution without touching your logic:

```
def bears(n: int) -> bool:
    if n == 42:
        return True
    elif n < 42:
        return False
    else:
        return (
           ((n % 2 == 0) and bears(n // 2)) or
           (((n % 3 == 0) or (n % 4 == 0)) and n>9 and n%10 and bears(n - (int(str(n)[-2]))*int(str(n)[-1]))) or
           ((n % 5 == 0) and bears(n - 42))
        )

print(bears(250))
```

(although I did fix an error you had in that complicated expression multiplying the last two digits, you messed up the parentheses.

Now the solution works because it either finds the answer, finds that an answer is impossible, or returns whether any of the alternatives leads to an answer (combining them with a logical `or`)

However, since we're now fixing your logic (after noting the `60` exception), here's a solution I'd use:

```
def my_bears(n: int) -> bool:
    return n > 41 and (
        (n == 42) or
        ((not n % 2) and bears(n // 2)) or
        ((not n % 3 and not n % 4) and n%10 * n%100 and bears(n - n%10 * n%100)) or
        ((not n % 5) and bears(n - 42))
    )
```

This fixes another case, like 102 - which will cause it to loop indefinetely, because 0*2 is still 0.

Comment: 250 works! But when I try making a print test case for 60, I get an infinite recursive error. Anyway to fix this one?

Comment: I admit to not testing many other cases, I've adjusted to account for that exception though